# Weird issues with non-english characters

Tags: c#, powershell, cmd

I have code automatically running netsh to check firewall rules:

```
var process = new Process
    {
        StartInfo =
        {
            FileName = fileName,
            Arguments = arguments,
            LoadUserProfile = true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true
        }
    };

        process.OutputDataReceived += (sendingProcess, outLine) => outputText.AppendLine(outLine.Data);
        process.ErrorDataReceived += (sendingProcess, errorLine) => errorText.AppendLine(errorLine.Data);
        output = outputText.ToString();
        errorOutput = errorText.ToString();
        //parse both outputs...
```

As a filename, I have the following command:

```
C:\Windows\System32\netsh.exe
```

And the following is the arguments:

```
advfirewall firewall show rule name="rulename" dir=in
```

It mostly works fine, its when output has non-english characters I run into issues. All of them are replaced with "?", so I thought this is encoding issue, but it looks like its not.

When I run same command manually in cmd, I get the very same result. However, if I change the font from default one to consolas, it shows non-english output perfectly fine.
How do I apply the same fix in my code and can I even do it at all? I searched for some time and found nothing, suggesting that I may be doing something wrong here.

Again, encoding doesn't seem to be an issue since both cmd and powershell show output after changing font correctly. I tried setting `StartInfo.StandardOutputEncoding` to the same encoding used in cmd but nothing is changed - I still get question marks in output. What am I missing?

EDIT: Tried setting StartInfo.StandardOutputEncoding to different values, including cp866, koi8-r and Windows-1251 - result stays the same, still getting question marks.

I'm trying to do this on Windows 2008 R2, with english as display language.

Comment: Sounds like a codepage problem. Which non-English characters would those be?

Comment: Just stick with Consolas font in your command windows. Where else do you see those question marks? Inside Visual Studio? With what program do you otherwise look at the text?

Comment: @vonPryz Mostly cyrillic. chcp shows 437 in both powershell and cmd(I didn't change them)

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen I get question marks in my code, in output strings. I don't need to look at text myself, I need to parse it and I can't do it with question marks instead of letters.

Comment: What were the values for `StartInfo.StandardOutputEncoding` you tried? Have you tried something like `Encoding.GetEncoding("cp866")` or `Encoding.GetEncoding("koi8-r")` or `Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1251")`? It seems to make a difference. For me, it will not work subscribing to those events you use (`OutputDataReceived` etc.). I just use `var output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();`. The same with standard error, of course.

Comment: Is the system language Russian? If so, I am surprised that `chcp` does not report 866. Which version of Windows?

Comment: @lit Edited my question.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Edited my question.

Comment: If English is your display language, why is netsh emitting Cyrillic characters? How did you set English as the "display language?" Have you tried `chcp 65001`?

Comment: @lit because some firewall rules have cyrillic letters in their names, so netsh outputs them. I got that machine as is and didn't change anything. netsh refuses to work with chcp 65001

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the rule names contain Cyrillic characters, then you are going to need to read them with an output console or editor that will display them.

In PowerShell, use the following and edit the output in WordPad or Word.

```
(New-object -comObject HNetCfg.FwPolicy2).Rules | ForEach-Object { $_.Name } >rules.txt
```

Comment: Not the most elegant solution, but it works. Thanks!